# How to Convert Listboxes All Items to Textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can  I convert `Listbox1` And `Listbox2` items to `Textbox`. ON Button Press..

Convert Format:>

> {Listbox1.item1/listbox2.item1} , {listbox1.item2/listbox2.item2} ,
>   {listbox1.item3/listbox2.item3}

and so on...

I tried many codes but didn't work...`

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each ListBoxLine1 As Object In ListBox2.Items

        For Each ListBoxLine As Object In ListBox1.Items
            TextBox1.AppendText(ListBoxLine.ToString & " / " & ListBoxLine1.ToString)
        Next ListBoxLine
    Next ListBoxLine1
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you already tried that didn't work?

Comment: "but didnt work" is not very helpful.  the compiler should be telling you that `& is not an operator for arrays` meaning you cant do that.  It also wont interleave/sort/group the LB items as shown in the format block.

Comment: your new code needs to account for cases where there are not the same number of items in each LB

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify this depending on how many listboxes there are.  This approach just creates a string array, interleaving the various LB items, then posts it to the TB after it is constructed.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(...

   Dim strText As String()              ' temp array

   ' get first listbox items as a string array:
   strText = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray

     ' rebuild array for each ListBox:
   strText = AddListItemsToArray(strText, ListBox2)
   strText = AddListItemsToArray(strText, ListBox3)
   ' etc

   ' post finished array to ML TB:
   tb.Lines = strText

End Sub
```

Then a small function to modify the array for each LB.  You could change this to augment the array for all the LBs at once (you'd have to consider ALL LBs for the count variable) but I have no idea how many there are.  This can also be used as Sub.

```
Private Function AddListItemsToArray(strT() As String, lb As ListBox) As String()
    ' use smallest size for loop index
    Dim count As Integer = Math.Min(strT.Count, lb.Items.Count) - 1

    For n As Integer = 0 To count
        strT(n) &= " / " & lb.Items(n).ToString
    Next

    Return strT
End Sub
```